# Printing E-mails - Outlook for Mac

Tags: microsoft-outlook, printing, office-for-mac

When printing an e-mail the "Attachment" icon and Attachment name do not print.  How do I change the settings to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that this is a feature included in Outlook for Mac. Take a look at this thread on [Microsoft answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macoutlook/how-do-i-print-multiple-emails-with-attachments-in/96da3e8a-eb0c-4302-b741-438ac18c6142?msgId=906e58a8-6429-4ec7-ac7b-9704890d5c21).

However, there do exist scripts to fix this issue, such as [this one at  OfficeforMacHelp](http://www.officeformachelp.com/2012/05/script-print-attachments/), which should work fine, though I have not tested them.